Snowflake connector with pyspark JAR packages error
I have read multiple thread on this but not found definitive answer.
I have running in container locally (mac os + podman)
scala: 'version 2.12.17'

pyspark: 3.4.0

spark-3.4.0

python 3.11.4 

I am running a container which is defined in compose (source: https://github.com/mzrks/pyspark-devcontainer/tree/master/.devcontainer)
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: .devcontainer/Dockerfile
      args:
        PYTHON_VARIANT: 3.11
        JAVA_VARIANT: 17
    volumes:
      - ..:/workspace:cached
    command: sleep infinity

  pyspark:
    image: jupyter/pyspark-notebook:spark-3.4.0
    environment: 
      - JUPYTER_ENABLE_LAB=yes
    ports: 
      - 8888:8888

I have almost everything that I could find to get this work:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

## I have also tried below

import os
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages net.snowflake:snowflake-jdbc:3.17.0,net.snowflake:spark-snowflake_2.12:2.16.0-spark_3.4 pyspark-shell'

## with and without what I have put here in packages_so and repository

packages_so = 'net.snowflake:snowflake-jdbc:3.4.0,net.snowflake:spark-snowflake_2.12:2.11.0-spark_3.4' 
repository = "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2"

## I have tried multiple versions of above, I dont really get what should the version
## numbers read like? other than the spark_3.4 means spark version?

spark = ( SparkSession
    .builder
    .master("local[*]")
    .appName("spark_docker")
    # .config("spark.jars.packages", "net.snowflake:snowflake-jdbc:3.17.0,net.snowflake:spark-snowflake_2.12:2.16.0-spark_3.4")
    .config("spark.jars.packages", packages_so) \
    .config("spark.jars.repositories", repository)
    .getOrCreate()
)

sf_options = {
    "sfURL": "url",
    "sfUser": "user",
    "sfPassword": "pass",
    "sfDatabase": "SNOWFALL",
    "sfSchema": "PIPELINE",
    "sfWarehouse": "COMPUTE_WH",
    "sfRole": "role",
}
SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME = "snowflake" # also "net.snowflake.spark.snowflake"
sdf: DataFrame = (
    spark.read.format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME)
    .options(**sf_options)
    .option("dbtable", "SNOWFALL.PIPELINE.MYTABLE")
    .option("fetchsize", "10000")
    .load()
)

sdf.show(vertical=True, n=2)

spark.stop()


I have also tried to run in my container shell (source: https://www.phdata.io/blog/how-to-connect-snowflake-using-spark/):
spark-shell --packages net.snowflake:snowflake-jdbc:3.17.0,spark-snowflake_2.12:2.16.0-spark_3.4

I just dont get how to add the JAR file to this instance so the connection works
and my error results always to:
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o152.load.
: org.apache.spark.SparkClassNotFoundException: [DATA_SOURCE_NOT_FOUND] Failed to find the data source: snowflake. Please find packages at `https://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html`.


I changed the values in config to net.snowflake:snowflake-jdbc:3.17.0,net.snowflake:spark-snowflake_2.12:2.11.0-spark_3.3" and restarted the kernel. Now it works with only .config("spark.jars.packages", <my-packages>
